# Android Issues with Apache http client android library

Tags: android, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient, androidhttpclient, vimeo-android

This is the library that I'm using:
https://github.com/clickntap/Vimeo

I'm trying to use the library for an Android app. My test device is Kitkat (4.4.4).

Here's my gradle config:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "my.app.package"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0-alpha"
}
```

Here's how I added the library:

```
compile 'com.clickntap:vimeo:1.10'
```

But I receive the following error on `Vimeo.addVideo()`:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder
```

and warnings:

```
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.6 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20140107 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
```

So I searched a little and found that I could do something like this:

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
compile('com.clickntap:vimeo:1.10') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    exclude group: 'org.json'
}
```

But now I'm receiving this error still on `Vimeo.addVideo()` and can't find any solution:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.entity.FileEntity.<init>
```

Please help :(

Thanks,

P.S.
Here's the stack trace for the 1st scenario:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder
                at com.clickntap.vimeo.Vimeo.apiRequest(Vimeo.java:218)
                at com.clickntap.vimeo.Vimeo.beginUploadVideo(Vimeo.java:122)
                at com.clickntap.vimeo.Vimeo.addVideo(Vimeo.java:138)
                at my.app.package.VimeoActivity$6.subscribe(VimeoActivity.java:163) // my activity
                at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleCreate.subscribeActual(SingleCreate.java:39)
                at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:2702)
                at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.run(SingleSubscribeOn.java:89)
                at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:451)
                at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:61)
                at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:52) 
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152) 
                at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265) 
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

And here's for the 2nd scenario, where the `httpclient-android` is included:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.entity.FileEntity.<init>
                at com.clickntap.vimeo.Vimeo.apiRequest(Vimeo.java:247)
                at com.clickntap.vimeo.Vimeo.uploadVideo(Vimeo.java:126)
                at com.clickntap.vimeo.Vimeo.addVideo(Vimeo.java:140)
                at my.app.package.VimeoActivity$6.subscribe(VimeoActivity.java:163) // my activity
                at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleCreate.subscribeActual(SingleCreate.java:39)
                at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:2702)
                at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.run(SingleSubscribeOn.java:89)
                at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:451)
                at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:61)
                at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:52) 
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152) 
                at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265) 
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Check section 'Apache HTTP Client Removal' in this page https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html . I guess it'll help this situation.

Comment: do you have a choice in libraries? I wouldn't use that library solely because it doesn't let me swap the underlying httpclient (it's forcing you to use apache... hence your problem)

Comment: thank you, I ended up creating my own android upload library following the vimeo api specs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android version<6 embedded a fork of Apache HTTP Client 4.0.beta snapshot (https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html).

The 1st scenario fails because `HttpClientBuilder` was introduced on httpclient:4.3.

The 2nd scenario fails because you are using both `useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'` that loads the legacy httpclient library and `compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'`. Vimeo client uses a FileEntity constructor that did not exist in the legacy library, which exists in the classpath and takes priority over the httpclient-android version of the FileEntity class.

I would suggest to use the dependencies as in the 2nd scenario, but remove `useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'`.

This solution will work with any dependency on `httpcomponents:httpclient` if you are using APIs that were introduced before or on 4.3.5.1 and not later, assuming that the public API of the httpclient-android library is identical to the httpcomponents:httpclient library of the same version.

**Update**

This solution will not work if your code or any of your dependencies use explicitly an API that has been replaced in the httpclient-android library in order to not conflict with the legacy httpclient version of the Android SDK.
org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient provides builders (e.g. HttpClientBuilder, EntityBuilder, MultipartEntityBuilder) which abstract the actual classes being used, that should be preferred. Unfortunately, both accessing "internal" classes/APIs and using Builders is possible (probably to maintain compatibility), but I believe that a single clean way should be permitted by the library.

In the above example, Vimeo library directly uses `FileEntity` constructor, which couples the library with a specific class, while this could be decoupled, if the `EntityBuilder` was used. So the only way I can see, is to modify the library source code, to make it compatible with httpclient-android library and Android in general.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I tried that but still got the `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.entity.FileEntity.<init>` error

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: thank you very much for the explanations! I see, I ended up creating my own android upload library following the vimeo api specs